# Excel Trailing Spaces

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column in an excel document that each entry has a trailing space. When I copy/paste the value into another form I have to manually remove the trailing space. Is there an easy way to batch remove all the trailing spaces through an entire column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its a 2 step process:

Use the TRIM function

```
=TRIM(Cell)
```

To remove the spaces. Basically make a parallel column that is TRIMmed. Copy the trimmed cells, then `PASTE SPECIAL` to paste the VALUES back to your original cells.

Clarified step by step:

- Make a new column with 
  `=TRIM(old column)` 
  in the cells
- Select that whole column (the new one with the formula)
- Copy that whole column
- Select the whole OLD column with the trailing spaces
- Right click it
- Select "Paste Special"
- Hit the radio button for "Values"
- Hit "OK"

Comment: So I select the column that has "=TRIM(CELL)" in each cell, copy it, then paste special on to the column that I need to be trimmed? That does not work for me.

Comment: Hmm, it should.  You may need to paste once more into a 3rd column to get a column with just the values to paste back into the target column.

Comment: It worked for me.  I'll clarify the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the content is numeric values with trailing spaces you can select the column, edit>copy
and into another column paste special>values>add and skip doing the trim. If it is text, do as mentioned previously by JNK